# How to convert MongoDB collection to Java object?

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-java

I am just starting out in the NoSQL (MongoDB) world and I am having a crash trying to convert my data collection to java objects for processing individually.

This is my collection that I get from mongo

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "5ebda019508257a3e39e2331"
  },
  "id": "1",
  "nombre": "Lalo",
  "apellido": "Tellez",
  "edad": "18",
  "habilidades": [
    "Android",
    "Tibco",
    "Web"
  ],
  "sueldo": "20000"
}
```

I have already made the connection to mongoDB and these would be the objects to which I would like to assign, with their respective `Getters` and `Setter`.

```
public class Empleado {
    private ObjectId _id;
    private int numeroRegistro;
    private String nombre;
    private String apellido;
    private int edad;
    private int sueldo;
}
```

I have not been able to advance because I cannot find a way to consume the mongo and assign each field to each object in java.
Thank you

Comment: Here are some code samples using [MongoDB Java Driver and Java Objects (POJOs).](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.12/driver/getting-started/quick-start-pojo/).

Answer (score 1):

As per your collection sample, I have assumed all your attributes 'String' type. For assigning to your POJO, here is the Java class.

```
import static org.bson.codecs.configuration.CodecRegistries.fromProviders;
import static org.bson.codecs.configuration.CodecRegistries.fromRegistries;
//Other Imports

public class MyClass {
public static void main(String[] args) {    
    MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient();

    //This registry is required for your Mongo document to POJO conversion
    CodecRegistry codecRegistry = fromRegistries(MongoClient.getDefaultCodecRegistry(),
            fromProviders(PojoCodecProvider.builder().automatic(true).build()));
    MongoDatabase database = mongoClient.getDatabase("mydb").withCodecRegistry(codecRegistry);
    MongoCollection<Empleado> collection = database.getCollection("mycoll", Empleado.class);

    //This assigns your collection to your list of Java objects
    List<Empleado> docs = collection.find(new Document(), Empleado.class).into(new ArrayList<Empleado>());
    for(Empleado doc:docs) {
        System.out.println("nombre="+doc.getNombre());
        System.out.println("apellido="+doc.getApellido());
        System.out.println("habilidades="+doc.getHabilidades());
        //Display other attributes of your Mongodoc
    }
    mongoClient.close();
}
}
```

Here is sample output:

```
nombre=Lalo
apellido=Tellez
habilidades=[Android, Tibco, Web]
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand your question you want each field from your `MongoDB document`. I assumed that you are passing your **`MongoDB document`** to the endpoint.
If you have a collection object and you want to extract each field then you have to parse this object and you will process further. So I used `**constructor injection**` and `**JSON parsing**`.
Also, You forgot to declare `habilidades` in the model but I have declared in the model.

- **This should be your model**

```java
    @Document
    public class Empleado {

        private ObjectId _id;
        private int numeroRegistro;
        private String nombre;
        private String apellido;
        private int edad;
        private int sueldo;
        private List<String> habilidades;

        public Empleado(ObjectId _id, int numeroRegistro, String nombre, String apellido, int edad, int sueldo,
                List<String> habilidades) {
            super();
            this._id = _id;
            this.numeroRegistro = numeroRegistro;
            this.nombre = nombre;
            this.apellido = apellido;
            this.edad = edad;
            this.sueldo = sueldo;
            this.habilidades = habilidades;
        }
        // Getters and Setters
    }
```

- **This should be your controller.**

```java
    @PostMapping("/insert")
    public void insert(@RequestBody String doc) {
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) new JSONParser().parse(doc);
                JSONObject obj = (JSONObject) jsonObject.get("_id");
                JSONArray array = (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("habilidades");
                Empleado empleado = new Empleado((ObjectId) obj.get("$oid"),
                        Integer.parseInt(jsonObject.get("id").toString()), jsonObject.get("nombre").toString(),
                        jsonObject.get("apellido").toString(), Integer.parseInt(jsonObject.get("edad").toString()),
                        Integer.parseInt(jsonObject.get("sueldo").toString()), array);
                // do something using getters and setters
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
```

I used [Simple JSON](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.googlecode.json-simple/json-simple/1.1.1) for parsing and I parsed your document as you mentioned in your question and I used constructor injection which is one type of [dependancy injection](https://martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html). You can also use the `setter` or `interface injection`.
You can perform all CRUD operation either using [MongoRepsitory](https://bezkoder.com/spring-boot-mongodb-crud/) or [MongoTemplate](https://lishman.io/spring-data-mongotemplate-crud-operations). Also, I suggest that use `MongoTemplate` for better execution.